# Is my code complex enough for switch statement usage in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, optimization, switch-statement

From Swift documentation:

> Typically, you use the if statement to evaluate simple conditions with only a few possible outcomes. The switch statement is better suited to more complex conditions with multiple possible permutations and is useful in situations where pattern matching can help select an appropriate code branch to execute.

I'm trying to decide on if I should use the switch or if/else statements based on if I have a complex condition. So my question is, is my condition complex or not.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
var sampleVar = Measurement(value: amount, unit: UnitLength.megameters)

if(type == "inches"){
     //do something
}
else if...
```

I have between 5 to 15 possible conditions I'm checking for so would that make it complex enough to justify using a switch statement? Or is complexity based on the condition and not how many conditions there are?

Comment: To clarify, are you just checking for 5-15 different possible values of "type"? If so, that sounds like a typical use case for `switch`. But ultimately the correct answer is whatever is easier for you to read and maintain.

Comment: Correct, I'm just checking for the 5-15 possible values of type. Thanks for the response! I think Switch is easier to read so I'll go with that.

Comment: The `"inches"` string is a code smell. You should probably be using polymorphism, or at a minimum, enums or dictionaries. https://smartflow.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/code-smell-stringly-typed/

Comment: You're probably also better off if you can convert `type` to an enum.

Comment: Never heard of "code smell" or "stringy code". Thanks for the answers, learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate test is to just write out both and compare.

## When `switch` is better

When you're dealing with a situation that favours a `switch` over an if/else ladder, you code will look like:

```
if something == 1 {
    foo()
} else if something == 2 {
    bar()
} else if something == 3 {
    baz()
} else { 
    quux()
}
```

As you can see, all the bracketing, repeated keywords (`else`, `if`) repeated operators `==` and repeated instance of the same identifier (`something`) add a bunch of noise with really little value. Compare to the `switch`:

```
switch something {
    case 1: foo()
    case 2: bar()
    case 3: baz()
    default: quux()
}
```

## When `if`/`else if`/`else` is better

You'll find yourself writing a switch where the switched variable isn't really being matched much, but instead you have a bunch of `where` clauses that check a lot of unrelated conditions. Compare:

```
switch something {
    case 1: foo()
    case _ where case2_1() || case2_2(): bar()
    case _ where case3(): baz()
    case _ where case4(): quux()
}
```

vs.

```
if something == 1 || case1() { foo() }
else if case2_1() || case2_2() { bar() }
else if case3() { baz() }
else if case4() { quux() }
```

## Don't forget about polymorphism!

Whenever possible, try to break up complex switching logic into dynamic calls to methods on an object. This allows you to separate the logic of each case into a separate class, where all related logic can be grouped.